# Add custom logic in the AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter so I can decide which requests to be filtered

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, spring-security

I am using the following filter AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter  from azure and in my WebConfiguration I have the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Profile({"dev", "test", "prod"})
protected static class AADWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter aadAuthFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(aadAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        log.info("Security enabled.");
    }
}
```

I have two scenarios:

In the first one the user is sending a request using the FE -> in this approach he is logged in with his account and I can do a role verification to see if it has the correct one. The way that I do the role verification is with using the annotation above the endpoints:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_tools-reader')")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFileForVariable(String processInstanceId, String 
variableName) {
```

In the second one another microservice is calling endpoint from another microservice. In order to be able to call endpoint I need also to send a jwt token and there is a way of how to get a token but without any roles. And in this case I am protecting these endpoints with the following logic:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public ResponseEntity<RentalCaseDTO> createRentalCase(CreateRentalCaseDTO createRentalCaseDTO) {
```

But if this endpoint is needed for the FE I won't be able to verify if it is a reader or writer and anyone can access this endpoint having any role.

I tried getting token from azure with roles but I was not successful. The logic of how I am doing that is the following:

```
public String getTokenFromAzure() {
    String token = null;
    ConfidentialClientApplication application = getApplication();
    if (application == null) {
        log.error("application is not instantiated");
    } else {
        ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(clientId + "/.default")).build();
        IAuthenticationResult auth = application.acquireToken(parameters).join();

        if (auth == null) {
            log.info("auth still == null");
        } else {
            log.info("idToken: " + auth.idToken());
            log.info("accessToken: " + auth.accessToken());
            token = isEmpty(auth.idToken()) ? auth.accessToken() : auth.idToken();
        }
    }
    return token;
}
```

What I currently want to achieve is to set some technical user in the header and override the AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter so all requests having that technical user in the header from other microservices won't be filtered at all even though they are protected by role. I am not sure if this is the right approach but I went into a dead end when I tried getting a token from azure with a specific role programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

As you are implementing 2 different use cases I would recommend to serve each from a different URL. That way you can hook up the filter to one and not the other.

Comment: I did that but I wanted to avoid having the same endpoints calling the same service logic twice.